# How to use permute on this Input and Target?

Tags: image-processing, pytorch, semantic-segmentation

I am having errors on my semantic segmentation masks with 5 classes + 1 (background).

How do I use permute to avoid this?

```
Target size (torch.Size([4, 1, 320, 480, 6])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([4, 6, 320, 480]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `permute` and `unsqueeze`:

```py
import torch

x = torch.rand((4, 6, 320, 480))
new_x = x.permute((0,2,3,1)).unsqueeze(1)
# new_x.shape = torch.Size([4, 1, 320, 480, 6])
```